# Why isn't my UILabel being changed inside queryPedometerDataFromDate?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Does anyone know why I can't get my UILabel to change inside queryPedometerDataFromDate, even though it will update just outside of it? I'm trying to post stepCount to the label after I run the query. At first I thought it was a NSNumber to String conversion issue, but both print statements are printing the same value to the console. Any guidance would be appreciated. I'm pretty new to this stuff.

```
var pedometer = CMPedometer()

    @IBOutlet weak var stepsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func queryStepCount(sender: AnyObject) {

        if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {

            let now = NSDate()
            let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
            let midnightOfToday = calendar!.startOfDayForDate(now)
            var stepCount = NSNumber(integer: 0)

            self.pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(midnightOfToday, toDate: now, withHandler: { (CMPedometerData, error) -> Void in

                stepCount = CMPedometerData!.numberOfSteps
                let convertedStepCount = stepCount.stringValue
                print("Converted Step Count:" + convertedStepCount)
                print (stepCount)

                // Why doesn't this change my label text?
                self.stepsLabel.text = "CHANGED"

            })

            // But this does...
            self.stepsLabel.text = "CHANGED"

        }
```

Comment: try to dispatch on main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query isn't being performed on the main thread, then the line `self.stepsLabel.text = "CHANGED"` will not update the UI. Try this...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.stepsLabel.text = "CHANGED"
})
```

Comment: Awesome. That fixed it!